# How to provide multiple attachment options in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint

In a sharepoint site I have a list called 'Assets'. Whenever a new Asset is added to this list I want to attach brochures and collaterals of this asset with the item.

Can I have 'Attach Brochure' and 'Attach Collateral' with same functionality as 'Attach File'?

I have to separate brochures and collaterals so that I can't use multiple attachment in single column.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is

1. Create Two Document Libraries one for Brochure  and Other for collateral
2. Let the user add those documents in that document Lib
3. In your Assets list add two Fields of type HyperLink and Paste the link to the docments there
4. Obviously you would want to avoid this extra step for which you can use a custom Field control that will upload and Paste the Link Refer [this link](http://www.hezser.de/blog/archive/2009/02/25/custom-field-%E2%80%93-upload-files-and-images.aspx) for Custom Control.